# Rotating position in a square grid

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I was asked a question about the following problem (maybe puzzle would be a better word), which originally came from programming. The person, who asked me this, was programming something involving 3-by-3 square. He decided to index the positions on the square like this:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
-------------
```

Later he found out that he wants to rotate the grid clockwise. So he needed map working like this: $1\mapsto 3$, $2\mapsto 6$, $3\mapsto9$, $4\mapsto2$, $5\mapsto5$, $6\mapsto8$ etc. And he noticed that he can get this map by using $n\mapsto 3n\bmod{10}$. His first question was:

> Why does this work?

I'll add the way I was able to explain this, but feel free to include better explanation, if you have one.

I have added a coordinate system to the table:

```
    -1   0   1
   -------------
-1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
   -------------
 0 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
   -------------
 1 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
   -------------
```

In these coordinates, the number in the square can be calculated as $x+3y+5$, where $x$ is the number of the of column and $y$ is the number of the row.

The clockwise rotation is given in this coordinate system by $(x,y)\mapsto(-y,x)$. Hence we want to have $f(x+3y+5)=-y+3x+5$. And the difference
$$3(x+3y+5)-(-y+3x+5)=10y+10$$
is indeed a multiple of 10.

---

A very natural question was:

> Can this be generalized?

The natural generalization I was able to think of was taking $n\times n$-square for $n=2k+1$. Again, I can index rows and columns by numbers $-k,\dots,-1,0,1,\dots,k$. Now the number in each row will be $x+ny+(n+1)k+1$. And multiplying by $n$ and taking reminder modulo $n^2+1$ will work:
$$n(x+ny+(n+1)k+1)-(-y+nx+(n+1)k+1)=(n^2+1)y+(n^2-1)k+(n-1)=(n^2+1)(y+k)$$

I would be interested to see other generalizations (if there are some):

---

Another natural question is:

> Can something similar be done, if I do not start indexing by 1, but by some other number (for example 0). If starting with 1 is the "best" or "most natural choice", what are the reasons behind it?

Can I get similar simple formula for rotating this table? (Since the numbers used here are 0,1,...,8; I would naturally expect something using modulus 9.)

```
-------------
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
-------------
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------
| 6 | 7 | 8 |
-------------
```

Comment: One thing that could be helpful for your last question probably is to look at the numbers in base 3. Then they are all 2-digit numbers, the lower digit being the x coordinate and the higher the y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

For the $3 \times 3$ case, you wrote the number for given coordinates $(x,y)$ as $x + 3y + 5$. This is only the condensed form of the general formula.

For a $(2k+1) \times (2k+1)$ grid centered at the origin, the $0$-based number in one cell for given $(x,y)$ coordinates is $(x+k) + (2k+1) (y+k)$. You can just add $1$ to obtain the original, $1$-based numbers

With this description, the problem turns out to be a purely geometrical one. You can rotate grids of arbitrary sizes (i.e. with arbitrary values for $k$). You can even *mirror* the grid by letting $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,y)$. Basically, you can use any affine transform, but few of them will produce results that intuitively make sense.

An interesting task could be the generalization of this for *even* grid sizes, e.g. for a $4 \times 4$ grid (I don't have the time to do this right now, but maybe will have another look at this later).

Answer (score 0):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$, we may multiply by any number coprime to $10$ and permute the elements.  Multiplying by $3$ partitions into two cycles of length 1 (namely $0$ and $5$), and two cycles of length $4$ (namely $2,6,8,4$ and $1,3,9,7$).  Using a different modulus is possible, provided that some of the cycles are completely unused.  Such a solution seems to break the spirit of the problem, though, unless the missing numbers are at the boundaries of the interval, like here (0 is at the boundary of $[0,9]$).

For this to work in a $4\times 4$ grid, you would need to work modulo $16$ or $17$, and find an automorphism that partitions into four cycles of length $4$.  It turns out that $13$ works, with modulus $17$.  They won't be arranged in the grid in the usual way; it was a great coincidence for the $3\times 3$.

```
  +----+----+----+----+
  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 13 |
  | 12 | 6  | 10 | 9  |
  | 8  | 7  | 11 | 5  |
  | 4  | 14 | 15 | 16 |
  +----+----+----+----+
```